# Best non-flash based technology to use for creating a web based online quiz with embedded videos for both Desktop and Tablet

Tags: adobe-captivate

I used to use Flash (Adobe Captivate) for creating CBT testing and tracking to a DB, but iPad tablet doesn't support flash, so I need to find a different technology. I also need to support older browsers like IE8 and am concerned about HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Captivate 8.  Best mode for what it sounds like you want is the Responsive Projects (which is not a powerpoint conversion).  It publishes in html 5 and runs on iPads and other mobile devices.  Seems to be several problems with Android devices, but translation to iPads for simple stuff is pretty sleek.  SWF output is still an option with Cap 8, but it won't run on tablets.

Warning - it is new technology and seems to have some bugs, especially with video on the iPad. Firefox on the iPad has problems, maybe Chrome too.  Personally I miss the design once, deploy everywhere days that we had with Flash.

Comment: Good to know that version 8 can publish html5. I think I have decided that I will still need to use a non Captivate product and develop a custom solution for my project that uses limited html5, but with a flash fallback for IE7 and IE8 video. Back to tables and 1996 approach for me. Any one else?